# How to format the JSON object key/value pair

Tags: json, node.js

I am new to nodejs, right now I am able to fetch the data from the database and display as REST API which is of key/value pair. My output looks like as shown below

```
[{"id":"793","actionname":"test_bsc_interface","actionid":"100"}].
```

But I need to format as

```
{ "header" : [id,actionname,actionid],

  "values" : [793 ,test_bsc_interface,100] ],}.
```

I tried with `JSON.stringfy` and checked few website but it's not working.

Could any one please help me through which link I should go through or approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do it is to use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) module to format it:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var data = [{"id":"793","actionname":"test_bsc_interface","actionid":"100"}];
var result = _.map(data, function(o) {
  return {headers: _.keys(o), values : _.values(o)}
});
console.dir(result);
```

Output is:

```
[ 
  { 
    headers: [ 'id', 'actionname', 'actionid' ],
    values: [ '793', 'test_bsc_interface', '100' ] 
  } 
]
```

To get the result you want, just do result[0]

Note that I use _.map() instead of data[0] because this will work for the array (your array result from the query) that has more than 1 item.

#### Revised answer according to your comment (1 header line and all value lines in an array):

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var data = [
  { id: '714', actionname: 'test_bsc_interface', actionid: '100' },
  { id: '715', actionname: 'list_all_available_interfaces', actionid: '103' },
  { id: '716', actionname: 'check_tt', actionid: '101' }
];

var result;

if (_.size(data) > 0) {
  result = {
    headers: _.keys(data[0]),
    values: _.map(data, function(o) {
      return _.values(o);
    })
  };
}

console.dir(result);
```

and the output is:

```
{ 
  headers: [ 'id', 'actionname', 'actionid' ],
  values: [ 
    [ '714', 'test_bsc_interface', '100' ],
    [ '715', 'list_all_available_interfaces', '103' ],
    [ '716', 'check_tt', '101' ] 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: I'd just like to add, that in newer versions of node (*0.12 I think*) those ES6-functions are already implemented. [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values), [keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) should work out of the box (but the syntax is slightly different).

Comment: Now i am able to fetch and dipaly the result as shown below

Comment: Thank you!! But I am getting json output array "{ 
    headers: [ 'id', 'actionname', 'actionid' ],
    values: [ '793', 'test_bsc_interface', '100' ] 
  } ,headers:['id','actionname','actionid'],values:['765','test']} repeatedly ,i used _.each and also try to fetch key[0]; .Could you please let me know which library i have to use

Comment: Hi Shilpa, I'm not sure what you meant, could you please clarify?  Please specify the input data and the desired output you'd like to have.

Comment: Json output after fetching data and exposing as REST API as shown  :: "[ { id: '714', actionname: 'test_bsc_interface', actionid: '100' }, { id: '715', actionname: 'list_all_available_interfaces',    actionid: '103' },
     { id: '716', actionname: 'check_tt', actionid: '101' } ] " but i need the output as  [{" headers " : [id,actionanme ,actionid ]," values" : [1,def,1234],[2,eder,345555]}] . I tried with lodash and _ module like _.each ,_.array .But i am not able to get output as expected, wherein each iterate will fetch header details as shown  in next comment

Comment: [{" headers " : [id,actionanme ,actionid ]," values" : [1,def,1234]," headers " : [id,actionanme ,actionid ],[2,eder,345555]}]

Comment: I see, you need to have just 1 header and all the values in an array.  In that case, there actually just a minor modification.  Please see my modified answer.