# Exposing RESTAPI through nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

Right now i am able to fetch data by quering postgres database  as  json output using nodejs as shown below

```
[{"headers":["id","name","description","type","actionmode","outputparser","dispatchtype","troubleticketaction","alarmaction","actionexecutionmode","cost","isparent__"],"values":["100","test_bsc_interface","test_bsc_interface","test","Open Loop","regex","HPSA",null,null,"Asynchronous",null,"0"]},{"headers":["id","name","description","type","actionmode","outputparser","dispatchtype","troubleticketaction","alarmaction","actionexecutionmode","cost","isparent__"],"values":["101","check_tt","check_tt","test","Open Loop","None","Trouble Ticket","check_tt",null,"Synchronous",null,"0"]}
```

I am expecting the output wherein duplicate headers should be avoided .Whats the approach for this ?  Below is the code snippet that i tried still its not working and i used _.each also .Please any one let me know the solution

```
var result = _.map(json_object, function(o) {
                    return {headers:keys[0], values : _.values(o)}
                });

[{"headers":["id","name","description","type","actionmode","outputparser","dispatchtype","troubleticketaction","","actionexecutionmode","cost","isparent__"],"values":["100","test_bsc_interfacalarmactione","test_bsc_interface","test","Open Loop","regex","HPSA",null,null,"Asynchronous",null,"0"]},,"values":["101","check_tt","check_tt","test","Open Loop","None","Trouble Ticket","check_tt",null,"Synchronous",null,"0"]}
```

Comment: Your JSON is seems to be invalid. Please provide the correct JSON

Comment: @Shilpa - you should update the question with the correct JSON

Comment: Hi Olimpiu , JSON format is as follow wherein i wan the output has

Comment: the same poster posted a similar question minutes after this one. there is the same invalid json there... I guess it becomes valid if you change the final } into ].

Comment: @Shilpa: if I am not mistaken, you are trying to avoid repeating column names for every row to save bandwidth/memory ... am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is from another post I answered:

[How to format the JSON object key/value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218194/how-to-format-the-json-object-key-value-pair/32218384)

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var data = [
  { id: '714', actionname: 'test_bsc_interface', actionid: '100' },
  { id: '715', actionname: 'list_all_available_interfaces', actionid: '103' },
  { id: '716', actionname: 'check_tt', actionid: '101' }
];

var result;

if (_.size(data) > 0) {
  result = {
    headers: _.keys(data[0]),
    values: _.map(data, function(o) {
      return _.values(o);
    })
  };
}

console.dir(result);
```

and the output is:

```
{ 
  headers: [ 'id', 'actionname', 'actionid' ],
  values: [ 
    [ '714', 'test_bsc_interface', '100' ],
    [ '715', 'list_all_available_interfaces', '103' ],
    [ '716', 'check_tt', '101' ] 
  ] 
}
```