# JSON output formatting

Tags: json

I am trying to format the JSON output through node js as shown below

```
[{"headers":["id","name","description","type","actionmode","outputparser","dispatchtype","troubleticketaction","alarmaction","actionexecutionmode","cost","isparent__"],"values":["100","test_bsc_interface","test_bsc_interface","test","Open Loop","regex","HPSA",null,null,"Asynchronous",null,"0"]},["101","check_tt","check_tt","test","Open Loop","None","Trouble Ticket","check_tt",null,"Synchronous",null,"0"]}
```

But currently i am  getting the output as shown below

```
[{"headers":["id","name","description","type","actionmode","outputparser","dispatchtype","troubleticketaction","alarmaction","actionexecutionmode","cost","isparent__"],"values":["100","test_bsc_interface","test_bsc_interface","test","Open Loop","regex","HPSA",null,null,"Asynchronous",null,"0"]},{"headers":["id","name","description","type","actionmode","outputparser","dispatchtype","troubleticketaction","alarmaction","actionexecutionmode","cost","isparent__"],"values":["101","check_tt","check_tt","test","Open Loop","None","Trouble Ticket","check_tt",null,"Synchronous",null,"0"]}
```

Please find code snippet that i have used : may know whats the changes required in the code ::

```
var json_string=JSON.stringify(rows,null,2);
            var json_object=setValue(JSON.parse(json_string));
            if (!err){
                console.log('The  object are returning ',json_object);
                var result = _.map(json_object, function(o) {
                    return {headers: _.keys(o), values : _.values(o)}
                });
```

Comment: working on it... both the jsons you provided don't parse correctly. I get something sensible changing the ending '}' in ']' in the first json you provided.

Comment: ...appending ']' at the end of the second json (the output you are getting) brings parsable results. also the js you provided has a problem with closing brackets (see the closing if block...). Also I am no expert in node.js, could you please clarify what the input (the 'rows' variable) is like?

Comment: Hi Leo ,I am pasting entire output and code below , Headers is repeating wherein i am not intersted the headers repetation .I tried fetching headers by library _.each ,but its not helping :(

Comment: [{"headers":["id","name","description","type","actionmode","outputparser","dispatchtype","troubleticketaction","alarmaction","actionexecutionmode","cost","isparent__"],"values":["100","test_bsc_interface","test_bsc_interface","test","Open Loop","regex","HPSA",null,null,"Asynchronous",null,"0"]},{"headers":["id","name","description","type","actionmode","outputparser","dispatchtype","troubleticketaction","alarmaction","actionexecutionmode","cost","isparent__"],"values":["101","check_tt","check_tt","test","Open Loop","None","Trouble Ticket","check_tt",null,"Synchronous",null,"0"]}]

Comment: you keep giving output... we need both a clean an intelligible INPUT and a clean and intelligible OUTPUT sample in order to help you. otherwise we have to proceed by trial and errors until we eventually hit the bull's eye. Why don't you just edit the question and make it a little more complete (parsable Input, parsable Output). I am sure me or somebody in this community will be able to help. in order to make sure your JSON parses well, check it here http://json.parser.online.fr/ before posting

Comment: anyway... I guess you need two steps. the first fetching the headers only, from the first row only, and the second looping and fetching data only.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be from another post I answered:

[How to format the JSON object key/value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218194/how-to-format-the-json-object-key-value-pair/32218384)

```
var json_string=JSON.stringify(rows,null,2);
var json_object=setValue(JSON.parse(json_string));
var result;

if (!err){
  console.log('The  object are returning ',json_object);
  if (_.isArray(json_object) && json_object.length > 0) {
    result = {
      headers: _.keys(json_object[0]),
      values: _.map(json_object, function(o) {
        return _.values(o);
      })
    };
  }
}
```